# Print a matplotlib.collections.LineCollection Object as Text (to String)

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to display a matplotlib.collections.LineCollection object as a string.

I created a violin plot using matplotlib. Consequently a dict was returned containing 'cmeans', among other values. I want to know what these means are but cannot figure out how to get them to display.

Doing `print(dic['cmeans'])` just returns `<matplotlib.collections.LineCollection object at 0x7f2534bf9c40>` which makes sense because `type(dic['cmeans'])` returns `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`. I cannot find any documentation for printing out a LineCollection object, everything is just showing me how to plot them. I don't want a plot.

I of course could just write a piece of code that finds the means but I expect I'll want some other values from that dict later on and don't want to have to manually calculate things that are already calculated for me, just in a weird state.

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm sure it's something stupid easy that I just don't know because I'm new to Python.